What kind of lightbulb is pictured here, having a clear bulb window and 4 yellow vertical rods?
I have a weird issue where different types of light bulbs are triggering some kinds of visual issues.
I found this lightbulb to be perfect. However, when I unscrewed it to read the label, it fell on the ground and broke!
What kind of lightbulb is it on the inside? Incandescent, halogen, flourescent, compact flourescent, LED, or something else? If it's LED, why are the LED rods shaped like that? And what are the keywords to find a similar bulb?


There is also a small circuit board inside the bulb end that I forgot to photograph.

https://www.livermoreca.gov/things-to-do/centennial-light-bulb "oldest" working lightbulb. Check out the BulbCam!!

Whether it flashes or not is down to how cheap they have made the electronics, nothing to do with the LEDs per se. You may have to try several different brands. I have put together a small phototransistor circuit that I can read with my DMM on AC to measure flicker amplitude and quantify what I can tolerate. Many brands flicker.

This is a LED filament bulb. The yellow rods are actually strings of blue LEDs mounted on an insulating substrate and coated in a phosphor than converts blue light to white.


Compared to a standard lightbulb like this one:

Advantages:

It is filled with helium which transfers heat very efficiently, so it uses the whole glass bulb as cooling surface, instead of just using the base. So it overheats less in closed light fixtures.

Very low cost.

Many LEDs in series means they can be driven with high voltage which is more efficient

Transparent, so the light that comes out at the back of the bulb is reflected by the fixture, goes through the bulb and comes out where you need it. So you get a lot more light for the same cost and power. Standard bulbs or diffused bulbs are in the way of the reflected light, so if the bulb is mounted sideways you lose a significant fraction of the output.


Drawbacks:

All the electronics has to fit inside the base so it must be very small, which means a small capacitor, so some of these bulbs flicker.

Easy to break (it's glass)

Exposed mains voltage when broken


Other:

Light pattern is the opposite of a standard LED bulb: it emits more towards the sides, whereas the standard bulb emits more towards the top. This makes it better for some uses, worse in others. Usually for wall or ceiling fixtures it is better, because the bulb is mounted parallel to the wall or ceiling. For a pendant or desk lamp where you need the light to come out more like a spotlight, standard would be better.

Arrows indicate direction of highest light output with bulbs in the best orientation according to their type:


if the LEDs are in series, would this mean one of them breaking will disable the entire rod? Or is that not a concern?

@Syndic Yes. Same as pretty much all other LED bulbs.

You might have added a bit more emphasis to the "why" in the question. The answer to that isn't physics or electronics but purely fashion: to make them look like old incandescent bulbs. No other real reason beside that. While illumination to the sides is practically true, this could have been achieved with countless other designs. This one was dictated by the supposedly fashionable retro look.

@Gábor The reason is cost and efficiency, which is also cost. Many LEDs in series allows driving with high voltage which simplifies electronics to almost nothing. No magnetics, no heat sink, no MCPCB, no expensive thermal conductive plastic... Manufacturing cost is extremely low.

You misunderstood my remark. :-) It was to the answer in general, not to the question of LEDs in series specifically. The reason for the whole design (transparent glass with LEDs resembling incandescent filaments and the inclusion of fake "filament holders") is obviously a market-oriented one, people wanting that retro vintage look and ready to pay a premium for it. Just as an example, it isn't important to me. I'm perfectly happy with all my LED bulbs having translucent enclosures without any filament look. All I want from them is light, nothing more. :-)

With the direction, looking at what is available today online, they seem to have changed it up a bit and are placing the filament in multiple angles to disperse light in more directions.

@Gábor Again, it's not just a look issue. It's heavily driven by distribution of light and luminous efficacy regulations (Energy Star, California Title 20). The US has the strictest quality of light requirements (e.g. 90+ CRI) in an effort to get holdouts to switch. The way they get the conventional bulbs to meet them are either multiple substrates (older Philips and Cree, bulky and expensive), remote phosphor (older Philips, expensive) or heavy diffusers (impact on efficacy).

@user71659 - I'm less sure, all that could be solved by any other form or shape of design. I switched all my car bulbs to LEDs quite a few years ago (EU, regulations only allow inside, not external lights unless original from the factory, but I mean those, anyway). While the voltage requirements are different, that's not why I mention it. It just happened to coincide with the arrival of the new COB technology. When I started, practically all those LED bulbs were combinations of 2020 and similar individual units in various enclosures, reflectors, whatnot.

Just after that, manufacturers (and I mean Aliexpress and similar) started to embrace COB technology and a lot of new bulbs appeared quickly with a multitude of internal shapes, also filament and larger surfaces. It simply became possible to put the design first (even when in automotive use, you usually never see the bulb itself) and they did. So, its not a question of efficiency, you could easily solve that with something that doesn't resemble the incandescent bulbs of the early 1900s. These bulbs are made like this because of the looks.

I bet many of the bulbs I currently use have the very same technology inside, just that it's inside a translucent enclosure and I couldn't care less whether it looks like an incandescent with filaments and holders way back when or not. :-)

It has become trendy for marketing to call LED bulbs with retro looking glass and bases "Edison Bulbs", but in industry as the article linked to above is supporting, Edison Base bulbs are the standard for the screw is style bulbs.  Their standard sizes all start with an "E" denoting Edison. Every standard screw in bulb is an Edison base bulb.  Marketing departments and people who do not know anything about lighting and its history or don't care, just like calling them "edison bulbs" and they are, just one specific retro looking type. I love the retro LED bulbs. Also, they have not dominated the market for "decades" it is more accurately a century+. Radio tubes are now about 120 years old! They were made possible by light bulb technology, putting filaments,plates, and grids in evacuated glass tubes.

You seem to have posted a response to one of the comments above, rather than an answer to the OP's actual question. StackExchange operates in a question-and-answer format, not as a discussion forum.

@MichaelMacAskill while this answer does contain obvious responses to a comment, it also manages to answer the OP's question "What kind of lightbulb" with "Edison Bulb". Though I think this answer needs a bit of editing to be a good SE answer

@someone Welcome to DIY SE! Please note the above comments and edit your answer to only respond to the original question

This is simply what is marketed as a "Vintage light bulb."  That's all there is to it.
You can instantly find these anywhere that sells bulbs or instantly see them for sale online.
If you simply google nothing more than "light bulbs" you will see many of these (incredibly stupid) "Vintage Style" light bulbs:


they are pretty much available on the shelf in most stores that carry bulbs these days, both in name brand and generic, and in all different shapes and sizes.  They aren't even labeled as vintage anymore, I know they used to be.
